# php move_uploaded_file always ends up in webroot

Tags: php, apache, file-upload

Whenever I use move_uploaded_file to my an uploaded file, the file always ends up in my web root. What am I doing wrong? Should the path be relative to my web root, or should it be an absolute path on my file system?

Ultimately what I'm trying to do, it have a folder for php to upload/dowload files. I don't want web bots and anyone else just to be able to access the files, i want only authenticated people using my website to be able to download the files. So this is how I have my file structure laid out:

```
/var/www/website/public_html
```

and

```
/var/www/website/files
```

and my move_uploaded_file command is like this:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['txtFileSelector']['tmp_name'], "/var/www/website/files/".$_FILES['txtFileSelector']['name']);
```

but no matter what i've tried, the file always ends up in
    /var/www/website/public_html
I've even tried sending the file in other sub folders of public_html but still no luck.

Comment: use move_uploaded_file($_FILES['txtFileSelector']['tmp_name'], getcwd() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'files/'.$_FILES['txtFileSelector']['name']);

Answer (score 0):

ah-ha! Destination path is relative!

So the solution for me is:

```
echo move_uploaded_file($_FILES['txtFileSelector']['tmp_name'], "../files/".$_FILES['txtFileSelector']['name']
```

Because of the relative pathing, use .../ to go up from the web root, and then move it to the desired storage folder.

CORRECTION

Absolute path or relative path either will work. It was a combination of folder permissions (www-data needs to either be owner or group member with read/write permissions) and me being an idiot and discovering a programming bug. My code was in a php class and the uploading was function. In my constructor I had a bug in my code. When doing OO there's a big difference between

```
$upload_dir = "/path/to/upload";
```

and

```
$this->upload_dir = "/path/to/upload";
```

Comment: The path is relative if you use a relative path. Since in your original post you're using an absolute path (starting with `/`), the path should be absolute. Something's weird here!